# Linux Mint only "File" menu visible on menu toolbar

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, gui, menu, toolbar

On applications like gedit and gimp  only the "File" menu is visible on the menubar/toolbar. However I can still click on where other menus would normally be (e.g. "Edit", "Help") to access them. I use Linux Mint 17.3 with Cinnamon 2.8.8. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: File menu is visible and accessible but Edit menu is not visible yet still acessible]

Answer (score 0):

I briefly had the same problem with GIMP version 2.8.16 in  Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia 64-bit, Kernel Linux 4.10.0-42-generic x86_64, MATE 1.18.0.
I guess the problem was with the theme.
As long as I used the Mint-X themes, I had the same problem.
The problem was solved by changing the theme to Ambiance, Radiance or any theme other than Mint-X series of themes. Though it does not address exactly what is causing the problem, at least it got solved.